# Why does my `lemma` environment has "Theorem" as a title?

Tags: ntheorem

I have written a macro `\createEnvironment{lemma}{Lemma}` that automatically creates several environments `lemma`, `lemma1`, `lemma2`, `lemma3` with different styles and whose title should be `Lemma`.

My problem is that the title is always "Theorem".

For example,

```
\begin{lemma}
Test
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma2}
Test
\end{lemma2}
```

will output

[image]

Why is it so and how to fix it?

### MWE

The following MWE does create the different styles but the title of all the environments is always "Theorem".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\theoremstyle{break}

% Style
\newcommand{\putFrameForEnvironment}[2]
{\tcolorboxenvironment{#1}{ colback         = white,
                            colframe        = black,
                            boxrule         = 0pt,
                            leftrule        = #2,
                            left            = 3mm,
                            right           = 0mm,
                            top             = 0mm,
                            bottom          = 0mm,
                            arc             = 0pt,
                            outer arc       = 0pt,
                            left skip       = 5mm-#2,
                            before          = {\vspace{3pt}},
                            oversize
                            }}
                            
\newcommand{\createEnvironment}[2]
{
 \def\zerothName{#1}%
 \def\firstName{#11}%
 \def\secondName{#12}%
 \def\thirdName{#13}%
 
 \newtheorem*{\zerothName}{#2}
 \newtheorem*{\firstName}{#2}
 \newtheorem*{\secondName}{#2}
 \newtheorem*{\thirdName}{#2}

\putFrameForEnvironment{\zerothName}{0mm}
\putFrameForEnvironment{\firstName}{1mm}
\putFrameForEnvironment{\secondName}{2mm}
\putFrameForEnvironment{\thirdName}{3mm}
}

\createEnvironment{lemma}{Lemma}
\createEnvironment{proposition}{Proposition}
\createEnvironment{theoreme}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
Test
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma2}
Test
\end{lemma2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differently from `amsthm`, `ntheorem` does no expansion on the first argument to `\newtheorem` or `\newtheorem*`.

If I ask for `\show\lemma`, I get

```
> \lemma=macro:
->\let \thm@starredenv \@undefined \csname mkheader@\zerothName \endcsname .
```

and you see the problem: you don't have `lemma`, but `\zerothName`. This has the last value it was set to.

I see no reason for using `\zerothName` and so on. But you could provided you switch to `amsthm`.

Here's a version where I also made a fix: you should use `before skip=10pt`, not `before={\vspace{10pt}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% if you want to change to amsthm
% \newtheoremstyle{break}%
%   {}{}%
%   {\itshape}{}%
%   {\bfseries}{}%  % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
%   {\newline}{}

\theoremstyle{break}

% Style
\newcommand{\putFrameForEnvironment}[2]{%
  \tcolorboxenvironment{#1}{
    colback = gray!20,% white,% just to see better
    colframe = black,
    boxrule = 0pt,
    leftrule = #2,
    left = 3mm,
    right = 0mm,
    top = 0mm,
    bottom = 0mm,
    arc = 0pt,
    outer arc = 0pt,
    left skip = 5mm-#2,
    before skip = 10pt, % <------- not "before={\vspace{10pt}}"
    oversize,
  }%
}

\newcommand{\createEnvironment}[2]{%
  \def\zerothName{#1}%
  \def\firstName{#11}%
  \def\secondName{#12}%
  \def\thirdName{#13}%
  \newtheorem*{#1}{#2}%
  \newtheorem*{#11}{#2}%
  \newtheorem*{#12}{#2}%
  \newtheorem*{#13}{#2}%
  \putFrameForEnvironment{#1}{0mm}%
  \putFrameForEnvironment{#11}{1mm}%
  \putFrameForEnvironment{#12}{2mm}%
  \putFrameForEnvironment{#13}{3mm}%
}

\createEnvironment{lemma}{Lemma}
\createEnvironment{proposition}{Proposition}
\createEnvironment{theoreme}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{lemma}
Test
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma2}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
\end{lemma2}

\end{document}
```

The gray background is just to better see the placement.

[image]

For comparison, this is the output I get with `amsthm`.

[image]

You can see that it's a bit better (look at the bottom of the boxes).

Comment: Thanks @egreg. My choice went to `ntheorem` because if I do a \begin{itemize} \end{itemize} right after \begin{theorem} then there is no new line skipped. If you have a solution for that without `ntheorem`...

Comment: @Colas Never start a theorem with `itemize`. If you want to use bad style, just add `\mbox{}` before `\begin{itemize}`.

Comment: Yes. But, is there a way to make it automatic?

Comment: Furthermore, `\mbox` inserts a white line before the `itemize`...